# what can be the optimized query for getting below result

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, bigdata

I have two tables:

1. Positions
2. Devices

i the millions of data in position table. i have one to many relationship with devices and positions. there are many positions for any devices.

Attributes of the position table are 
`id`, `deviceid`, `servertime`,  `latitude`, `longitude`,  `attributes`

And data sample for position table is

```
`3127557`, `2`, `'2019-08-08 09:00:16'`, `27.72634`, `85.303055`, `'{\"ignition\":false,\"status\":4294949887,\"io1\":\"429\",\"io2\":\"02\",\"io3\":\"00104\",\"io4\":\"33312\",\"distance\":1.98,\"totalDistance\":1215137.92,\"motion\":true}'`;


┌─────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬───────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   id    │ deviceid │     servertime      │ latitude │ longitude │                 attributes                  │
├─────────┼──────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────┼───────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 3127557 │        2 │ 2019-08-08 09:00:16 │ 27.72634 │ 85.303055 │ "ignition":FALSE, "status":4294949887,      │
│         │          │                     │          │           │ "io1": "429", "io2": "02", "io3": "00104",  │
│         │          │                     │          │           │ "io4": "33312", "distance":1.98,            │
│         │          │                     │          │           │ "totalDistance":1215137.92, "motion":TRUE   │
└─────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Additional Information: i have totalDistance index in attributes column in json format which will increase in ever ytime new position will added.

Now i need to retrieve the daily report of the distance traveled by bus between certain interval of dates like between 2018-08-23 to 2018-08-30.

```
select deviceid, min(id), max(date(id) from posiotins
    where deviceid in [2,3,6]
    group by date(servetime)
```

Save those ids in an array ids[] and

Again `Select * from postions where ids in [ids] order by deviceid, id`

then i have subtract the totaldistance from consecutive  2th value to 1st value to get the daily distance traveled report

Comment: Why are you computing `max(date(id)` when you don't use it?

Comment: They gives me the first and last instance of the positions for each day of each device. i had save them in the array and passed it in another query as array.

Comment: You are losing the distance moved between just before midnight to just after.

Comment: You say "certain interval of time" -- Do you mean _dates_ or _seconds_?

Comment: I mean to say dates, I have edited the question.

Comment: Are these busses in Katmandu?

Comment: yes, and i think you had verified by the coordinate given in the question. hahaha

Comment: The bus driver stopped for tandoori on the Ring Road at the Lumbini Garden Cafe?  (Google maps are fun.)

Comment: select * into #p from positions where date between 'startofday' and 'endofday'
select deviceid,dense_rank(date asc)dasc,dense_rank(date desc)ddesc,km into #data from devices d join #p p on p.deviceid=d.id
delete from #data where dasc>0 and ddesc <> 1
delete from #data where ddesc>0 and dasc <> 1
select deviceid, case when dasc=1 km as kmstartofday, case when ddesc=1 km as kmendofday,  from #data group by deviceid

Answer (score 1):

You have a scaling problem.  The sooner you tackle it, the better.  There are millions of rows *now*, but it is headed for *billions*, correct?

A simple, but partial, fix is to add a 3rd table that is the data for each vehicle at about midnight every night.  A simple way to do that, *during ingestion*, is to record the first datapoint after midnight for each vehicle.

What computes "total distance"?  It smells like an odometer.  If so, it is very simply provided by the vehicle.  If, instead, you are adding to it for every record that comes in, then...

- How often do you need it updated?  Daily would be more efficient.  Up-to-the-minute gets more complex and costly.
- What do you compute it from?  Does the vehicle give incremental distances?  Or are you computing with lat/lng?

The third table that I mentioned should probably have `total_distance` as a column, not buried in JSON.  And/or it should have `distance_for_the_day`.

Think about the ultimate query -- "how far did this vehicle go in the past week".  See how much simpler and faster it will be from the new table.

Comment: that the great idea but i can edit the database table. And the database will be archived and reset to every instance it 100 million of data. So i need to optimize the query. I had same type of problems in another one too. So, if there is any optimization solution for that i can used that in another problem too.

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA - Yes, there are tradeoffs.  What about the "edit"?  Would you be changing values that were already folded into `total_distance`?  One approach is to recompute the rows for the day that was edited.  (Hopefully, it is rare.)  Read also about Summary Tables: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA - "archived and reset" -- this can be costly.  See [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) for how to do it efficiently with partitioning.

Comment: Yes, but i have no any access over the connectivity of Geo-device  and database. And only solution remaining will be optimization. And thanks for your valuable words.